# DD4T | Enable LinkLevels for Multimedia Fields only

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1, dd4t, dd4t-2

How can I enable **LinkLevels** parameter for Multimedia fields only ?

While checking the parameters schema, something close I can see is the Parameter: **FollowLinksPerField**

Below is what the description says: 
[image]

What field setting(s) is needed to allow LinkLevels follow Specific field only? By specific field, I mean Multimedia fields especially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arvind, did you check this out already - I suspect it's exactly what you're looking for?

[Blog Post on DD4T Field-level link resolving](http://blog.trivident.com/improving-link-resolving-in-dd4t/)

Comment: Exactly the solution I am looking for!!